# css postion:block <span> on same line

Tags: html, css

Does anybody tell my Error because i need to put the slogan (its where life happens) line below the "OUTDOORS "

[image]

```css
.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.header-primary {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-primary-main {
  display: block;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 25px;
}

.header-primary-sub {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 14px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="text-box">
    <h1 class="header-primary">
      <span class="header-primary-main">outdoors</span>
      <span class="header-primary-sub">its where life happens</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: It is working fine here
https://jsfiddle.net/uzd9gfLm/

Comment: its working fine. so what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try using `position:absolute`

```css
.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg);
}

.header-primary {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-primary-main {
  //display: block;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 25px;
}

.header-primary-sub {
  ///display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  width: 101%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="text-box">
    <h1 class="header-primary">
      <span class="header-primary-main">outdoors</span>
      <span class="header-primary-sub">its where life happens</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</header>
```